# Биодуховная субстанция

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Редактирую текст. В тексте встретилось слово "биодуховный". Когда я указал автору, что это слово некорректно, он ответил, что в его понятии дух - живая материя, субстанция. Я закавычивал это слово, чтобы указать на необычность.

Вопрос: как в сноске можно коротко объяснить читателю, что именно подразумевается под этим словом? Ни из текста, ни из контекста читатель понять не сможет, о чем  идет речь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...Он ответил, что в его понятии дух - живая материя, субстанция.

Ответ автора не проясняет лексического значения слова "биодуховный", не зафиксированного словарями.

Но само слово - живое и не неологизм; нет причин его кавычить.

В разных текстах (не только в практиках йоги и аюрведы) мне встретились

биодуховная система, биодуховная модель, биодуховная связь, биодуховные энергии, биодуховный подход, биодуховный метод, биодуховный индикатор,  биодуховный рост, биодуховное состояние, биодуховное событие etc.

Например:

> ...Распад семьи болезненно отражается на детях. Даже когда не осознают
>   этого факта. Это кощунство над ними. Особенно при нарушении
>   целостности семьи, в которой маленькие дети. Дело не только в том, что
>   у ребенка не будет «настоящего» папы. Травматично для него то, что
>   разрывается биодуховная наследственная связь. То есть нарушается
>   природосообразное коммуникативное взаимодействие «родитель — ребенок»
>   и «ребенок — родитель», а потому прерывается энергетическая и
>   информационная подпитка ребенка.

Так себе текстик, но речь о частотности словоупотребления...

Или:

> Коллективные и биодуховные энергии, поддерживающие все укорененные в
>   земле культуры, контрастируют тому, что дает технологический ум
>   человека ради увеличения личного комфорта и владения материей.

Если делать сноску для читателя (а я бы не стала), то пояснять термин следует исходя из значения приставки (или первой части сложных слов) "био" + любое слово.

> **БИО...** [от греч. bíos - жизнь] Первая часть сложных слов. **1.** Обозначает отнесённость чего-л. к живым организмам, их состоянию,
>   жизни. *Биодатчик, биогенетический, биомолекула, биоритм, биосистема,
>   биосфера, биоэкономика.*

Нам достаточно [первого значения](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE) (приставка многозначная).

Вообще-то автор сказал о соединении материального, клеточно-биологического и... духовности, которую нельзя пощупать руками. Плоть + Дух. Именно эта парадоксальная дуальность названа им особой субстанцией.

Надо ли это пояснять читателю?

> Человек - это сложная биодуховная система...

Comment: Galina,  в том-то и дело, что био - приставка, означающая отнесённость чего-л. к живым организмам, их состоянию, жизни, а дух неживая, нематериальная субстанция. Я попытался найти в интернете, но ничего не нашел. Подумал, авторский неологизм, и вот и решил закавычить.

Comment: В смысле - поезд ушёл? Правка внесена и отыгрыванию не подлежит?

Comment: Да, я закавычел. Но объяснение в сноске не дал. Автор хотел напечатать текст в журнале, но не думаю, что примут. Слишком много несвязок, огрехов, нет смысловой и композиционной целостности текста.

Answer (score 1):

Не считаю слово "биодуховный" некорректным. В специальной литературе его даже не закавычивают. По аюверде это "биодуховность" - взращивание духа. Если этого недостаточно, то отослать к самой аюверде.

Вот если автор что-то свое имел в виду, не каноническое, то тут, конечно, надо разбираться. Из Ваших комментаприев совершенно не ясно, о чем вы там с ним договорились.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37960/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus--).